# Is a crystal needed for burning firmware on AVR?

Tags: avr, crystal, isp

I want to program an AVR attiny2313 with my AVR ISP MKII

So I built a header that connects to a breadboard where I want to burn the firmware to the ATTiny via ISP,

so my question is,

I have a design that uses an external Crystal of 16MHz

but I don't have space on the actual protoboard for the ISP header,
so can i upload the firmware with out a Crystal [will configuration of fuses work?] and then use it the proper external Crystal ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have an oscillator as prescribed by the current fuse settings in order for programming to work. If the current fuse settings specify the internal oscillator then you can program the fuses to use an external crystal instead, but once you do so you will then require an external oscillator in order to perform subsequent serial programming. Parallel programming will still be available, since it is clocked independent of the system oscillator.